# Icons for bootbox js dialogs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Has anyone figured out how to add icons to the buttons in a bootbox.js dialog? I'd like to add icons to the "No" and "Yes" buttons in this function:

```
$(function () {
    $(".confirm-delete").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).data('id')
        bootbox.confirm("Remove this product?", "No", "Yes", function(confirmed) {
            if(confirmed) {
                deleteRecord(id);
            }
        });
    });     
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a custom dialog and use the `icon` configuration option [added in 2.1.0](https://github.com/makeusabrew/bootbox#210).

For example:

```
$(function () {
    $(".confirm-delete").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).data('id')
        bootbox.dialog("Remove this product?", [{
            "label" : "No",
            "icon"  : "icon-remove"
        }, {
            "label" : "Yes",
            "icon"  : "icon-ok icon-white",
            "callback": function() {
                deleteRecord(id);
            }
        }]);
    });     
});
```

[Custom dialog example](http://bootboxjs.com/#gist4340421)

Answer (score 1):

```
bootbox.confirm({
    title: "Destroy planet?",
    message: "Do you want to activate the Deathstar now? This cannot be undone.",
    buttons: {
        cancel: {
            label: '<i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cancel'
        },
        confirm: {
            label: '<i class="fa fa-check"></i> Confirm'
        }
    },
    callback: function (result) {
        console.log('This was logged in the callback: ' + result);
    }
});
```